# how to return model from controller to view using jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Code in javascript

```
function SubmitQuery(Org_UID) {

        var ddlProduct_No = $("#Org_UID");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowNewProfessionalWindow", "UpdateOrganizationUID")',
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                countryno: $("#Org_UID").val() }
```

My Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowNewProfessionalWindow(string countryno)
    {
          UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel model = new UpdateOrganizationUIDViewModel();
            //model.Org_UID = OrgUID;
            model.org_name_long = "test";
            model.org_name_short = "test";


            return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
        }
```

How can I return value of model to view using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonResult`

Change your code and return `JsonResult`, So use

```
return Json(model);
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
```

**If you want to return View use**

First you can create a method as, which will accept `ViewName` and `Model` it will return HTML string

```
public static string RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model)
{
    controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View,
                controllerContext.Controller.ViewData, controllerContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage also you have to return `JsonResult` instead of `PartialViewResult`

```
public JsonResult yourpartialviewresult()
{
    return Json(new
            {
                data = RenderRazorViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "partialview", model)
            });
}
```